# Disable a validation in View MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, validation

I have a confused case with my project

My Modeler like

```
public int ReasonSelected { get; set; }
public bool CardSelected { get; set; }
```

and `ReasonSelected` is a required field just if the `CardSelected` is true!

in the `View` I put a `for` statement as I have about 3 types of cards and what I need is to only show the validation message just if the user select the card so other unselected cards shouldn't raise the "Must select reason" error message

Only if the user select a card, so must select a reason ... `ReasonSelected` validation should only works with selected cards not others

Answer (score 1):

You could write a [custom validation `[RequiredIf]` attribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx). You could bring this a step further and [implement IClientValidatable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) to perform client side validation.